# Create a histogram for only specific value of a variable

Tags: r, histogram

I have a dataset with 2 variables. One variable is the day of the week (7 possible values) and the other variable is a numeric value.

I want to make a histogram with numeric values only when they are corresponding to a Monday. I have attached a screenshot of my dataset.

Should I create a dataset only Monday's value? How could I do that?

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM32O.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to subset your dataframe directly in `ggplot2` by using `subset`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = subset(df, Day_Week == "Monday"), aes(x = total_price_diff_from_lowest))+
   geom_histogram()
```

Is it what you are looking for ?

If not, please consider providing a reproducible example of your dataset by following this guide: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and to clarify what kind of plot you are looking for.

NB: `ggplot2` is a package for making all kind of plot (see: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/) but it is not installed by default in R, so you will have to install it using `install.packages("ggplot2")`. If you are looking for a solution using `base r plot`, please see @RonakShah's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could subset the `total_price_diff_from_lowest` values where `Day_week` is `"Monday"`

```
hist(df$total_price_diff_from_lowest[df$Day_week == "Monday"], 
      main = 'Histogram for Monday', xlab = 'Price_Diff')
```